# Multiple Image Field in Django Model

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I am using django-cms for a client project. I want to add a carousel of images that will display all those images in my template. How do I add this using a model and implement it into a form to use?

```
class Show(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=300)
    header_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="", blank=True)
    starting_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.today, blank=True)
    poster = models.ImageField(upload_to="", blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    is_TS_show = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    show_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.show_slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Show, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/show/%s/" % self.show_slug
```

It's for a carousel so it will be maybe 4-5 pictures.

Comment: use one-to-many relationship?

Comment: @Fabricator what would be the best way to implement a 1tm relationship in a form? e.g uploading multiple images.

Comment: i've not done it, but i would try [inline forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) for the images